# ошибка автозапуска скрипта systemd ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash, iptables, sudo, systemd

/etc/systemd/system/fixttl.service

```
[Unit]
Description=ttlfix 
After = syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=True
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fixttl.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/usr/sbin/fixttl.sh (-rwxr-xr-x root root)

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j TTL --ttl-set 65
```

sudo systemctl status fixttl.service

```
fixttl.service - ttlfix
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fixttl.service; disabled; vendor
preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

ttl не меняется , подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема

Comment: `RemainAfterExit=yes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Уберите sudo из скрипта и добавьте путь к iptables: /sbin/iptables
2. Выполните от рута `systemctl enable fixttl.service`
3. Выполните от рута `service fixttl start`
4. Убедитесь, что правило прописалось в фаерволл: `iptables -t mangle -L -v -n` (от рута)
5. Если прописалось, перезагрузитесь и убедитесь, что всё в порядке.

Comment: большое спасибо , помогло

Comment: @alphalph и да: 0. Читайте документацию :)